# Sort applications in app center by number of downloads

Tags: appcenter

this is not a typical question, but a suggestion what would be great to see in the further development of elementary OS.

I've been a user of various linux distributions for several years now and stayed on elem-OS. I have my favorite apps and I know how to search for new ones.

I would like to introduce the elementary OS to my girlfriend, but also I would like to prevent actions like that she call me every time when she's looking for new fine apps ;)

Sorting apps by popularity (like number of downloads) would help to show the best applications to less advanced users.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is coming! It will only be tracking the most popular apps submitted to AppCenter by third party developers rather than the ones inherited from the Ubuntu repositories.

You can see a screenshot of this feature in action from Daniel Foré's G+ post here:
[https://plus.google.com/+DanielForé/posts/WUuyVvDo8ve](https://plus.google.com/+DanielFor%C3%A9/posts/WUuyVvDo8ve)

The hope is that there will be a good enough variety of applications submitted to AppCenter so that the Non-curated Ubuntu applications no longer need to be used as much.